# ec2 upstart, what is the `start on` command to wait for network

Tags: amazon-ec2, upstart, network-interface

Firstly this is a double post with serverfault, Please advise what is better site for this type of question.

This is my first time with upstart. I can not get the following script to launch when waiting for the network to initiate. It will work if using standard

```
 start on runlevel [2345]
 stop on runlevel [!2345]
```

I have also tried various combinations of

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=eth0
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
```

Any suggestions would be grateful

```
description "test for on network start"


start on (started network-interface
      or started network-manager
      or started networking)

stop on (stopping network-interface
     or stopping network-manager
     or stopping networking)


script
    touch /home/ec2-user/myFile.txt
end script
```

Answer (score 0):

the event that signifies that the network is completely configured is static-network-up. You will most likely also need the file system event for any service that uses /home, /var, and /usr.